# Designating all cells which contains a specific word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I"d like to make a scatter graph as shown in the following picture:

[image]

For designating X values, I want to range cells which contain the specific word, e.g., "4SF".

[image]

For instance, when plotting "4SF", I'd like to use the date in G23:G33 even if the date is sorted in some rules.

[image]

But, in that cases (when sorting), the range G23:G33 is changeable. How can I designate that area as X values?

Please teach me how to input at X values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question right, but do you mean the following? (When using office 365 or excel online):
`=FILTER(G:G,D:D="4SF")`

This will result in all values of column G where column D shows value `4SF` in the same row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, P.b. Yes, your understanding is right, but unfortunately, I'm using Office for Mac 2019 not Office 365. Do you have any other alternatives?